# jquery simple carousel animation previous element movement

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to create a simple carousel using jquery.
**HTML**

```
<div class="block-13">
<div class="list-wrapper">
    <ul class="list row">
        <li class="col-xs-12">
            <table>
                <tr class="row">
                    <td class="col-xs-8">
                        <div class="item item-1">
                            <div class="text">test1</div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="col-xs-4">
                        <div class="item-name">
                            <div class="text">test11</div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </li>
        <li class="col-xs-12">
            <table>
                <tr class="row">
                    <td class="col-xs-8">
                        <div class="item item-1">
                            <div class="text">test2</div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="col-xs-4">
                        <div class="item-name">
                            <div class="text">test22</div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </li>
        <li class="col-xs-12">
            <table>
                <tr class="row">
                    <td class="col-xs-8">
                        <div class="item item-1">
                            <div class="text">test3</div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="col-xs-4">
                        <div class="item-name">
                            <div class="text">test33</div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="show-more next">next</div>
<div class="show-more prev">prev</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
var width = $('.block-13 .list li').width();

function carouselNext() {

    $('.block-13 .list').filter(':not(:animated)').animate({
        right: '+=' + width
    }, 500, function () {

        var first = $('.block-13 .list li:first-child');
        first.remove();
        $(this).append(first);

        $(this).css({
            right: '-=' + width
        });
    });
}

function carouselPrev() {

    $('.block-13 .list').filter(':not(:animated)').animate({
        right: '-=' + width
    }, 500, function () {

        var last = $('.block-13 .list li:last-child');
        last.remove();
        $(this).prepend(last);

        $(this).css({
            right: '+=' + width
        });
    });
}

$('.block-13 .show-more.prev').click(function () {
    carouselPrev();
});

$('.block-13 .show-more.next').click(function () {
    carouselNext();
});
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/93PhD/12/**

`function carouselNext()` works correct and the blocks move smoothly. but I can't get a smoothly animation for `function carouselPrev()`.
How to make it work the correct way ?

Comment: why you use += -= ? why you use .remove() ? theres a better way to do it. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/YFgAM/. Prepend the element before you start the animation.

```
$('.block-13 .show-more.prev').click(function () {
    var last = $('.block-13 .list li:last-child');
    last.remove();
    $('.block-13 .list').filter(':not(:animated)').prepend(last);

    $('.block-13 .list').filter(':not(:animated)').css({
        right: '+=' + width
    });

    $('.block-13 .list').filter(':not(:animated)').animate({
        right: '-=' + width
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

On PREV click:

- .prepend() the :last LI element
- kick left (-width) the slider
- animate

This is all you need:

```
var $list = $('.block-13 .list');
var width = $("li", $list).width();

function next() {
  $list.animate({left: -width}, 800, function(){
    $(this).css({left:0}).append( $("li:first", $list) );
  });
}
function prev() {
  $list.prepend( $("li:last", $list) ).css({left: -width}).animate({
    left: 0
  }, 800);
} 

$('.show-more').click(function () {
  return $(this).hasClass('prev') ? prev() : next();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Just replace right to left in `function carouselPrev()`

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/93PhD/13/)

Comment: `carouselPrev()` became the same as `carouselNext()`. It's definitely not that I need.

Comment: Low quality and untested answer.